# Tkinter place widgets from a list using a loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to place a bunch of labels on a window using a list of coordinates. The loop generates a bunch of label objects and appends them to a list. However, when I try to read from the list of objects and run commands on them (`pack()` or `place()`), only the last called label displays on the screen.

```
root = Tkinter.Tk()
...
coordinates = [[25, 40], [410, 40], [650, 40],
               [35, 180], [200, 180], [410, 180], [655, 180]]
labels = list()
interval = int()
message = "Hello, do you wanna push to master?".split(' ')
for index in range(len(coordinates)):
    if coordinates[index][1] < 100:
        labels.append(Tkinter.Label(root, text=message[index]))
    else:
        labels.append(Tkinter.Label(root, text=message[index]))
    root.after(interval, lambda: labels[index].place(x=coordinates[index][0], y=coordinates[index][1]))
    interval += 500
```

In the code above, only the label with "master?" would display on the screen, though it appears at the correct coordinates with the right styling. I can get different labels to display by changing the last index with `range(len(coordinates) - 1`, `range(len(coordinates) - 2`, etc., but only ever one at a time. Note that all the labels display fine if I manually assign them to variables and call them without a loop.

Comment: The code here won't run without modification.  Please post a running example.

Comment: The code runs fine, just add the `import Tkinter` to the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` loop assigns reference to `index` not value in

```
lambda: labels[index].place(x=coordinates[index][0], y=coordinates[index][1])`
```

so you need `lambda i=index:`

```
lambda i=index: labels[i].place(x=coordinates[i][0], y=coordinates[i][1]))
```

---

My version

```
import Tkinter

coordinates = [[25, 40], [410, 40], [650, 40],
               [35, 180], [200, 180], [410, 180], [655, 180]]
message = "Hello, do you wanna push to master?".split(' ')

labels = []
interval = 0

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("750x210")

for (x,y), msg in zip(coordinates, message):
    lab = Tkinter.Label(root, text=msg)
    labels.append(lab)
    root.after(interval, lambda a=x,b=y,l=lab:l.place(x=a, y=b))
    interval += 500

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This works! However, I don't understand why adding an argument for the `lambda` works the way it does. The function has access to labels and index regardless, does it not, since they are defined in a higher scope?

Comment: Inside `lambda` python puts reference to `index` - not value from `index`. Python get value from `index` when `lambda` is called. Meanwhile `index` has changed. After `for` loop `index == len(coordinates) == 7`  so every lambda use the same value 7 in `labels[7].place(x=coordinates[7][0], y=coordinates[7][1])`.  `lambda i=index:` copy value from `index` to `i` and all `lambda` use different values.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `root.after`and just have this line.

```
labels[index].place(x=coordinates[index][0], y=coordinates[index][1])
```

Or if you really want the delay on start-up, then remove `lambda`

Comment: I'm fairly new to Tkinter. Can you explain what removing the `lambda` does? I tried it and it displays all the elements, but all at one instead of staggered one after another. The window displays much later.